# What is the relation between ring of integers of $O_{K_i}$ and $O_K$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let us consider the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $\pi$ be the uniformizer of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Consider the finite extensions $K_i$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by adjoining  $(p^i-1)^\text{th}$ roots of $\pi$, i.e., $K_i=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[p^i-1]{\pi})$ such that $K_i \subseteq K_{i+1}$. Then take union $K=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty K_i$. Then $K$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $O_{K_i}$ and $O_K$ are ring of integers in $K_i$ ad $K$ respectively.

**My question-** What is the relation between $O_{K_i}$ and $O_K$ ?

It may be $O_{K_i} \subseteq O_K$ or it may be $O_{K_i} \not\subset O_K$, if I am not wrong. It also may be $O_K|_{K_i}=O_{K_i}$, i.e., restriction of $O_K$ to $K_i$ is $O_{K_i}$.

But I am not sure of the above line.

Please answer my question.

Comment: May I know the reason why downvoted my question ?

Comment: Why are you not sure of the third to the last line? What is the issue here that gives confusion?

Comment: @SungjinKim, actually I just want to verify my intuition. What about the first $2$ claims of the last?

Comment: I just downvoted because your question is trivial, also the tower depends on the chosen $\pi$ (if you meant $\pi=p$ then...) as well as on the chosen roots of $\pi$ (even if the latter are isomorphic since the ramification degree is $p^i-1$ so $\zeta_{p^i-1}^m \pi^{1/(p^i-1))}$ is conjugate to $\pi^{1/(p^i-1)}$). Do you know what is the definition of the unique extension of the valuation to $K$ and what is the definition of $O_K$ ? More interesting: can you find the Galois group ? What is the completion of $K$ and do the automorphisms extend to it ?

Comment: @reuns, it is not a matter if you really feel that my question deserve downvote. But I did not understand why the choice of $\pi$ matters? Second, please clarify the relations between $O_K$ and $O_{K_i}$ in different possible cases as you think, if possible in a answer form.

Comment: @reuns, if you asking the Galois group of $K_i$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then it(the Galois group) is a cyclic group of order $p^{[K_i: \mathbb{Q}_p]}-1$. But I don't have idea of the Galois group of the algebraic extension $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Comment: Yes it was a test :) the choice of $\pi$ is the same as the choice of a $p^i-1$-th root (because $(1+p a)^{1/(p^i-1)}$ is in $\Bbb{Z}_p$) so (if the sequence of $p^i-1$-th roots is compatible) they are all conjugates. No idea why you are affraid by the big Galois group (of the normal closure). It is the $\varprojlim$ of the smaller Galois groups, ie. $\varprojlim Z/(p^i-1)\cong \prod_{prime \ P \ne n} Z_P$

Comment: For the big Galois group of the normal closure (adding the roots of unities) it contains  the $\varprojlim$ of the smaller Galois groups, ie. $\varprojlim Z/(p^i-1)\cong \prod_{prime \ P \ne n} Z_P$, plus the Frobenius acting of the roots of unities, and the two mix according to a simple Galois module law.

Comment: @reuns, oh!, thanks for the big Galois group. But can you please comment on the relation between $O_K$ and $O_{K_i}$ as the last line of my question? Is my intition correct?